# Ubuntu isn't recognizing the mic from my Bluetooth headset

Tags: ubuntu, audio, bluetooth, microphone

So I bought the Motorolla Vervebuds 400 and they pair right away with the Blutooth from my notebook and the sound is awesome. The only problem is that Ubuntu isn't recognizing the microphone, and it's driving me crazy.

[image: The devices pairs right away without any problem]

[image: In the OUTPU dropdown in the sound settings, I can choose the VerveBuds 400 and that works excellent, but in the INPUT dropdown there's no other option that the default mic (and it doesn't even work)]

The headset: [Motorolla Vervebuds 400](https://www.motorola.com.au/vervebuds-400-compact-true-wireless-in-ear-headphones-black/p)

The laptop: [Lenovo ThinkBook 14s IML](https://psref.lenovo.com/syspool/Sys/PDF/datasheet/ThinkBook_14s_IML_datasheet_EN.pdf)

- Ubuntu version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-10510U  CPU @ 1.80GHz × 8
- Graphics: Mesa Intel® UHD Graphics (CML GT2)
- OS Type: 64-bit
- GNome Version: 3.36.8

The output of running `dmesg | grep -i blue` :

```
[    2.416446] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.416464] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.416467] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.416468] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.416474] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.425116] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware revision 0.0 build 121 week 36 2020
[    3.421990] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.421992] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.421995] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   28.164559] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[   28.164565] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[   28.164569] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Comment: Try "apt install --reinstall pulseaudio pulseaudio-module-bluetooth".

Comment: That didn't work at all. I don't think the problem has to do with the Bluetooth module but rather with the audio module that won't recognize any microphone except the one from my wired headphones.

Comment: Okay, audtio/bluetooth software has been updated and restarted. Note the microphone generates the audio. And the headset and microphone are most likely using different bluetooth profiles.  If you have another OS confirm the microphone works. Maybe change with the input device - see what happens - or maybe play with "/usr/bin/sdptool".